# How to combine multiple rows and check if variables match

Tags: r

I am quite new with R. I was wondering if there could be a  simple solution for my situation.

I have this kind of data set with 3 duplicated datas.

**A**

```
       CARDID BSTN ASTN USERTYPE INVDIST INVTIME  BSEC TRNID BSTN.r ASTN1 BSTN2 TRNID2 ASTN2 BSTN3 TRNID3 ASTN3 BSTN4 TRNID4 ASTN4 BSTN5 TRNID5 ASTN.r
2406     5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
2406.1   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
2406.2   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
4037     9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
4037.1   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
4037.2   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
       ASEC.r tr_in tr_out
2406    22234     0      0
2406.1  22234     0      0
2406.2  22234     0      0
4037    20547     0      0
4037.1  20547     0      0
4037.2  20547     0      0
```

And another data set that looks like this. The second dataset consits of columns. They are subsections of the columns in  the first data set

**B**

```
   BSTN tr_in ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5  ASTN tr_out 
1   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   151      0  
2   150   426   422   205     0     0     0     0     0     0   151    201     
3   150  4201  4203   239     0     0     0     0     0     0   151    201
```

- Is there a way I can cbind these two data sets?
  I tried duplicating the second data set and used cbind(A,B) but the results were "LARGE MATRIX" form that I cant see.
- Is there a way I can compare the first data set and the second data set to check if they match?
  Which is why I tried to column bind them but would there be a simpler solution?

========Edited=========
What I would like to create is

```
       CARDID BSTN ASTN USERTYPE INVDIST INVTIME  BSEC TRNID BSTN.r ASTN1 BSTN2 TRNID2 ASTN2 BSTN3 TRNID3 ASTN3 BSTN4 TRNID4 ASTN4 BSTN5 TRNID5 ASTN.r
2406     5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
2406.1   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
2406.2   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
4037     9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
4037.1   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
4037.2   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151
       ASEC.r tr_in tr_out  BSTN tr_in ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5 ASTN tr_out  match
2406    22234     0      0   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    151    0     1
2406.1  22234     0      0   150  4201  4203   239     0     0     0     0     0     0   151    201    0
2406.2  22234     0      0   150  4201  4203   239     0     0     0     0     0     0   151    201    0  
4037    20547     0      0   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   151      0    1
4037.1  20547     0      0   150   426   422   205     0     0     0     0     0     0   151    201    0 
4037.2  20547     0      0   150  4201  4203   239     0     0     0     0     0     0   151    201    0
```

So if I compare data set A, B , I want to add a new column to A  showing 1 if they match and 0 if they don't

Comment: `cbind` suggests that both frames have the same number of rows, these do not. I suspect you need a `merge` operation here, but I can only guess/infer what logic would be used here. It would be informative (perhaps for you, too) for you do manually create what you think this should look like (*completely*, for these 6-row and 3-row frames), and explain what logic you use to assign each row from `B` multiple times into `A`.

Comment: @r2evans I edited my question Thank you

Comment: Your intended output is still confusing: you start with a 6-row and a 3-row frame, and your output looks like a naive cbinding of a 6-row `A` and a 2-row `B`. Why did you arbitrarily drop `B[3,]`? What made `A[1,]` "match" `B[1,]`? What is the intent of the blank rows in `C[3:6,]` (where `C` is your intended output)? Do all of the numbers in `A[1,]` really pair solely with `B[1,]`, or are you trying to find matches in some other fashion **between all rows** in `A` and all rows in `B`? Your logic is still unstated.

Comment: @r2evans Im truly sorry for the bad explanation. English isnt my first language. The blank rows in C should be filled. yes. The output I want is columns in B binded to A with a new column showing whether the variables in B match the variables in A. If they do match I would like the new added column to be 1, 0 if they dont match. This is why I tried to duplicate B[1:3] to  match the number of  rows in A, and then compare B with A to mark either 1 or 0 if the values in the same name of columns match

Comment: Your english is fine, it's the logic that is confusing me :-) So `A[1,]` always pairs with `B[1,]`? Is there something inherent to the data that means that `A[4,]` has no business trying to compare with (say) `B[2,]`? Is there a column that is intended to be "in-common", so that rows in `A` with one value are compared with rows in `B` with this same value?

Comment: @r2evans Yes A[1,] pairs with B[1,]  but there are only 3 rows in B so A[1,] will pair with  B[1,] . If you look carefully at A, you could see that I duplicated data sets times 3 to check if they match with B. the reason i duplicated 3 times is because B has three rows. I edited my question once more to make the output clear. Sincerely thank you for the effort

Comment: Okay, you just said that `A[1,]` pairs with `B[1,]`, but you also show valid comparison of `A[4,]` with `B[1,]`. Either `nrow(A)` is always a perfect muliple of `nrow(B)`, or you don't care that your comparison of rows is arbitrarily skipping some. Is that right? Also, when you say "compare", do you mean *"values of all columns that they have in common are identical"*? Does order of columns matter? Is your ultimate goal to find out which rows in `A` are also in `B`, and if so, which row in `B`?

Comment: @r2evans In fact, I don't even need to combine B to A , I just need to add a columns to A showing whether it matches the variables in B. 1 if they match 0 if they don't

Comment: @r2evans Yes nrow(A) is a muliple of B because I dupliated the datas in A times  nrow(B). and you are correct . I mean "values of all columns that they have in common are identical", and "the order of columns does not matter".  I just need to check if the values are identical in the same columns in A and B And yes my ultimate goal is to find out which rows in A are also in B .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be holes in the logic here, but I'll state some assumptions:

- `nrow(A)` is always an integer-multiple of `nrow(B)`; this means that `A[1,]` pairs only with `B[1,]`, `A[2,]` with `B[2,]`, ..., `A[4,]` with `B[1,]`, `A[5,]` with `B[2,]`, etc.
- the test of *comparison* is "equality of in-common columns"

If those are true, then

```r
incommon <- intersect(colnames(A), colnames(B))
incommon
#  [1] "BSTN"   "ASTN"   "ASTN1"  "BSTN2"  "ASTN2"  "BSTN3"  "ASTN3"  "BSTN4"  "ASTN4"  "BSTN5" 
# [11] "tr_in"  "tr_out"
Bplus <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                 c(replicate(nrow(A) / nrow(B), B, simplify = FALSE),
                   list(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
Bplus
#    BSTN tr_in ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5 ASTN tr_out
# 1   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  151      0
# 2   150   426   422   205     0     0     0     0     0     0  151    201
# 3   150  4201  4203   239     0     0     0     0     0     0  151    201
# 11  150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  151      0
# 21  150   426   422   205     0     0     0     0     0     0  151    201
# 31  150  4201  4203   239     0     0     0     0     0     0  151    201
A$match <- +(rowSums(A[,incommon] == Bplus[,incommon]) == length(incommon))
A
#        CARDID BSTN ASTN USERTYPE INVDIST INVTIME  BSEC TRNID BSTN.r ASTN1 BSTN2 TRNID2 ASTN2
# 2406     5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0
# 2406.1   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0
# 2406.2   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0
# 4037     9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0
# 4037.1   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0
# 4037.2   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0
#        BSTN3 TRNID3 ASTN3 BSTN4 TRNID4 ASTN4 BSTN5 TRNID5 ASTN.r ASEC.r tr_in tr_out match
# 2406       0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0     1
# 2406.1     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0     0
# 2406.2     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0     0
# 4037       0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0     1
# 4037.1     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0     0
# 4037.2     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0     0
```

The use of `+(...)` is a trick to convert `logical` to `integer` 0 and 1. It is just as easy to keep `$match` as a `logical` field by removing that portion of the assignment. (I only used it because you had that in your intended output. I prefer `logical` for my own use, since `1` or `1L` implies ordinality and *perhaps* that there can be more than two values of 0 and 1. In a declarative sense, `logical` clearly states that you expect only `FALSE` and `TRUE`, and possibly `NA` when it is indeterminant.)

Also, the `rowSums(...) == length(incommon)` checks that all of the in-common fields are identical. Another way to calculate it is

```r
apply(A[,incommon] == Bplus[,incommon], 1, all)
```

which might be more intuitive and/or declarative. The choice of which to use is a lot based on preference and a little on performance ... the `rowSums` method is slightly faster than the `apply` method.

---

### Data

```r
A <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
       CARDID BSTN ASTN USERTYPE INVDIST INVTIME  BSEC TRNID BSTN.r ASTN1 BSTN2 TRNID2 ASTN2 BSTN3 TRNID3 ASTN3 BSTN4 TRNID4 ASTN4 BSTN5 TRNID5 ASTN.r ASEC.r tr_in tr_out
2406     5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0
2406.1   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0
2406.2   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0
4037     9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0
4037.1   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0
4037.2   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0")
B <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
   BSTN tr_in ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5  ASTN tr_out
1   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   151      0
2   150   426   422   205     0     0     0     0     0     0   151    201
3   150  4201  4203   239     0     0     0     0     0     0   151    201")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I sincerely appreciate your work. Works perfectly and the explanations are amazing. Thank you evans.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way I can compare the first data set and the second data set to check if they match?**

**Code:**

```
library('data.table')
col_nm <- names(df2)[names(df2) %in% names(df1)]
setDT(df1)[df2, on = col_nm, nomatch = 0]
```

**Output:**

```
#    CARDID BSTN ASTN USERTYPE INVDIST INVTIME  BSEC TRNID BSTN.r ASTN1 BSTN2 TRNID2 ASTN2 BSTN3 TRNID3 ASTN3  BSTN4 TRNID4 ASTN4 BSTN5 TRNID5 ASTN.r ASEC.r tr_in tr_out trips
# 1:   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0  0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0  1143
# 2:   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0  0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0  1143
# 3:   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0  0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0  1143
# 4:   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0  0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0  1143
# 5:   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0  0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0  1143
# 6:   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0  0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0  1143
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 'CARDID BSTN   ASTN USERTYPE INVDIST INVTIME  BSEC TRNID BSTN.r ASTN1 BSTN2 TRNID2 ASTN2 BSTN3 TRNID3 ASTN3 BSTN4 TRNID4 ASTN4 BSTN5 TRNID5   ASTN.r  ASEC.r tr_in   tr_out
                         2406     5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0
                         2406.1   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0
                         2406.2   5786  150  151        6    1100     340 21996  1672    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  22234     0      0
                         4037     9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0
                         4037.1   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0
                         4037.2   9737  150  151        6    1100     320 20368  2191    150     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0     0     0      0    151  20547     0      0', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = 'BSTN tr_in ASTN1 BSTN2 ASTN2 BSTN3 ASTN3 BSTN4 ASTN4 BSTN5  ASTN tr_out trips
1   150     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0   151      0  1143
                  2   150   426   422   205     0     0     0     0     0     0   151    201     2
                  3   150  4201  4203   239     0     0     0     0     0     0   151    201     2', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```